Datatrigger on all cell in Datagrid
i need to compare two snapshots of DB and change the cell color in Datagrid if there is a difference between them.
Each row in the DB equal of an object.
With the use of Datatrigger i can change the cell color by using another property of the object (Name_Modified) like this code:
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name_Modified}" 
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

But what if need to do the same on all columns? ( i have something like 45), each column is different, do i need to add a Datatrigger on all columns? and add another property to the object to get a "flag" if something is different?
I'm sure there is something more accurate to do but i can't find it.
Thank you for your help

Cant try it out at the moment, but couldn't you define a local style extension for a Column under DataGrid with the appropriate Trigger?

I would probably go the route of adding a property to the database values themselves, rather than adding multiple [XXX]_Modified properties.
In the example below, I built a DataTable during validation that captures whether or not a column changed. This allows the style to be the same for each cell.
ValidatedData.cs
    public class ValidatedData
    {
        private string _value;

        public string Value 
        { 
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                if (_value == value) return;
                Changed = true;
                _value = value;
            }
        }

        public ValidatedData(string value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public bool Changed { get; private set; }
    }

Code Behind
    public partial class ConditionalTextColumn : Window
    {
        public ConditionalTextColumn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            Data = new DataTable();
            Data.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            Data.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(ValidatedData));
            Data.Columns.Add("Comments", typeof(ValidatedData));

            foreach (var item in StartingData)
            {
                var name = new ValidatedData(item.Name);
                var comments = new ValidatedData(item.Comments);

                var updated = UpdatedData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id);
                if (updated != null)
                {
                    name.Value = updated.Name;
                    comments.Value = updated.Comments;
                }

                var newRow = Data.NewRow();
                newRow["Id"] = item.Id;
                newRow["Name"] = name;
                newRow["Comments"] = comments;

                Data.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }

        public List<DbData> StartingData { get; set; } = new List<DbData>
        {
            new DbData { Id = 1, Name = "Name 1", Comments = "Comments 1"},
            new DbData { Id = 2, Name = "Name 2", Comments = "Comments 2"},
            new DbData { Id = 3, Name = "Name 3", Comments = "Comments 3"},
            new DbData { Id = 4, Name = "Name 4", Comments = "Comments 4"},
        };

        public List<DbData> UpdatedData { get; set; } = new List<DbData>
        {
            new DbData { Id = 1, Name = "Name 1", Comments = "Comments 1"},
            new DbData { Id = 2, Name = "New Name 2", Comments = "Comments 2"},
            new DbData { Id = 3, Name = "Name 3", Comments = "New Comments 3"},
            new DbData { Id = 4, Name = "Name 4", Comments = "Comments 4"},
        };

        public DataTable Data { get; set; }


    }


XAML
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="validationTextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Changed}"
                                        Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="Yellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="Text"
                            Value="{Binding Value}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Name}"
                                       Style="{StaticResource validationTextBlock}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Comments}"
                                       Style="{StaticResource validationTextBlock}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>


Result

